# How can I keep my current architecture of the back end while separating my local and remote data sources?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, interface, repository, dagger-2

So long story short, trying to utilize googles good practices. I made a mistake of  going dagger 2 for the project Di. And now I am stuck. I followed along the [Sunflower architecture](https://github.com/android/sunflower)
I am trying to separate local data(ld) source and remote data(rd) source while if possible keeping the architecture I have. I currently have 2 data sources ld and rd that implement datasource interface. And my repository only recognises functions from that interface. In the googles example they share the same functions across both data sources, while my project diverges from that and they should have different functions. (Ld should insert quotes into DB while remote should just fetch quotes)

I've tried making a new interface that implements the datasource but is specific to local data source, and that didn't work, keep getting a missing binding error from dagger.

[Github project](https://github.com/Nikola-Milovic/QuoteAppMvvm/tree/Backend)

```
interface QuoteDataSource { //data source interface for both data sources

    suspend fun getQuotes(): Result<List<Quote>>

}
```

```
class DefaultQuoteRepository @Inject constructor( 
    @ApplicationModule.QuoteRemoteDataSource private val quoteRemoteDataSource: QuoteDataSource,
    @ApplicationModule.QuoteLocalDataSource private val quoteLocalDataSource: QuoteDataSource,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : BaseRepository(), QuoteRepository {
```

```
 @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @QuoteRemoteDataSource
    @Provides
    fun provideQuoteRemoteDataSource(
        jsonNetworkService: JsonNetworkService
    ): QuoteDataSource {
        return QuoteRemoteDataSource(jsonNetworkService.apiService)
    }

    @JvmStatic
    @Singleton
    @QuoteLocalDataSource
    @Provides
    fun provideQuoteLocalDataSource(
        database: LocalQuoteDataBase,
        ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher
    ): QuoteDataSource {
        return QuoteLocalDataSource(
            database.quotesDao(), ioDispatcher
        )
    }
```

```
class QuoteLocalDataSource constructor( // for fetching locally stored quotes, might save favorite quootes or save the json quotes
    private val quotesDao: QuotesDao,
    private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO
) : QuoteDataSource {

    override suspend fun getQuotes(): Result<List<Quote>> = withContext(ioDispatcher) {
        return@withContext try {
            Success(quotesDao.getQuotes())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.Error(IOException("Unable to fetch quotes!"))
        }
    }


class QuoteRemoteDataSource @Inject constructor(
    private val apiService: QuoteApi
) : QuoteDataSource {

    override suspend fun getQuotes(): Result<List<Quote>> {
        val response = apiService.getQuotes().await()
        try {
            if (response.isSuccessful)
                if(!response.body().isNullOrEmpty())
                return Result.Success(response.body()) as Result<List<Quote>>
            return Result.Error(IOException("Error occurred during fetching quotes!"))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Result.Error(IOException("Unable to fetch quotes!"))
        }
        return Result.Error(IOException("Unable to fetch quotes!"))
    }
```

I am somehow trying to have localdata source have its own functions that are recognised by the default quote repository. As if i just add functions to the localds they won't be available to the repository.

Comment: You could for example delete the Repository entirely, read only from Local data source with `LiveData<List<T>>` for example to get updates, and the "remote data source" would fetch then directly write fetched data into local DB

Comment: That... That might just be it thank you